# How to open specific web browsers using hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

I have a simple app which contains a link, I want on mobile apps eg LinkedIn  people to click this link and open it in a browser eg safari

I tried this

```
<a href="safari-https://meed.audiencevideo.com">May open on Safari</a>'
```

When I click this link it opens in a native LinkedIn app browser in iPhone

what do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: so what do I need to do to open it in a system browser? let assume user have a deafult browser installed eg safari?

Comment: I meant I have a simple website just html and JavaScript website,  here it's https://meed.audiencevideo.com,now I have added a link which I want users to click it , after clicking it should Open the link in a system browser not in app browser eg LinkedIn or Skype browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser that gets used is a user setting on the device based on what they have installed, not something you can control.  Best you can do is recommend that it works best in Safarior or whichever browser.

Comment: I get it , assume user have installed safari , is it possible to redirect to safari browser?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks):

The short answer you can't specify that a specific browser will be opened by a hyperlink.

If you are viewing a web page or an app or something that shows a hyperlink and you click on that link then the operating system will receive an event that indicates a hyperlink was launched. It will then look for the default browser, launch that browser and then pass the URL to the browser.

You can change the default browser at any time but the operating system will only open that specify browser.

If you were really determined you might be able to write multiple browser launcher browsers that you would register with the operating system. Then any time you clicked on a link your browser would launch and you could present yourself with a list of alternative browsers to open the link with.

FYI Safari has an option to open the current web page in another browser. It is in menu bar near developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure the edge browser such way- but i couldnt found any solution for other browsers

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://meed.audiencevideo.com">May open on edge</a>'
```